# Keeping one column and adding words in text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with five columns. I want to keep last column. Then I want to add a link such as "www....." with the last column's remaining text. I have 150,000 rows. But I need to add only one common link. 
Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: please provide sample data, and sample output you want.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Post your code

Comment: sample data:
company   year      cik  filetype      fileextension
A                 2000    21   10-k          data/1000/21/q4.txt

I want:
to keep fileextension
and want to add " www.sec.edgar" before "data/1000/21/q4.txt"
that means, my final output would be like this:
www.sec.edgar/data/1000/21/q4.txt